# django OperationalError when trying to migrate with docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known`
That is the error I get when running *docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate*
my *docker-compose.yml* contains:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:11
```

This Is what I put for DATABASE in *settings.py*:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

I have tried running *docker-compose up -d --build* and then *docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate*
But that doesn't work.

Comment: `HOST` should be `localhost`.

Comment: @RichaBhuwania - No, it shouldnt. Although you should add that as an answer if you believe its correct.

Comment: Did you check that the db container is still up? `docker-compose logs db` or `docker-compose ps` might give you a hint.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add an environment for your `db` service:

```
services:
  # ...
  db:
    # ...
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

as `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` is the only non-optional env variable needed to run the image as stated in [the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres).